# Hosting a website in azure Virtual Machine Scale Set

Tags: azure, azure-functions, autoscaling

I'm new to azure, I have created a virtual machine scale set that automatically adds VM in accordance with cpu usage. I want to host a web based application in here with the help of IIS. I have 1 default instance and I have RDP to that. new instances are formed when the scale criteria is met and the old one might get deleted. How do I host a website here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [build your custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#build-a-custom-vm-image) that includes your web-based application and IIS, then make your VMSS based on your custom image. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-powershell

Or you can install an app on your VMSS with a custom script extension instead of RDP to each instance. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#already-provisioned